# How to handle websites in Android when keyboard appears

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I have a webpage that at the bottom has a form, so visitors can send their emails. When I visit this webpage from my Android (Galaxy SIII) and try to enter the email in the input box the keyboard becomes visible and the design a total mess. In chrome the page scrolls up and gets bigger. In the default explorer (it is just called Internet) the design works better but after sending the form, the keyboard disappears and the page scrolls upwards. I have not found any good solution to this problem. My test URL is at http://tandemprueba.comlu.com/

How could I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent scaling up try to change your viewport meta tag with this one:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1;' />
```

Comment: I still have the problem